# How to simulate a click event for show/hide on a :before element (icon) with css?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to simulate a click with CSS that would trigger a show/hide on a :before psuedo element with only CSS?

NOTE: I can not change the HTML.

I have a js fiddle showing what I have com up with so far. It is only working with a :hover though. I would like it if someone could click the font-icon and then show the list items. If there is not a way to do this with CSS only, can someone help me to implement a javascript solution?

```css
.cat-parent:before{
  content:"\f067";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:250px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.children{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.cat-parent:hover ul{
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="sidebar">

<ul class="product-categories">
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-253 cat-parent"><a href="#">Various Fruits</a> <span class="count">(21)</span>
          <ul class="children">
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-255">
                  <a href="#">Apples</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
               </li>
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-254">
                  <a href="#">Oranges</a> <span class="count">(20)</span>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: You cannot simulate clicks with CSS.  Just bind an event handler in js.

Comment: The closest you could come is adding an `:active` pseudo-class selector and show the menu items when it is applied. But someone would have to actually click on the element to make it work.

Comment: While you can't simulate 'click', you may want to explore `:focus` and / or `:active` psuedo-classes.

Comment: So you want `.cat-parent` is clicked, then change max height of ul to 100% like your hover?

Comment: That said, it would have to be the anchor that gets the `:active` (or `:focus`), rather than the `:before` pseudo-element since [pseudo-elements can't gain the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31578901/215552).

Comment: You can achieve what you want if you can use the anchor as the target with css `.cat-parent > a:focus ~ ul`

Answer (score 0):

An idea *(but more a hack than a good idea)* is to use `tabindex` and `:focus` to simulate a click on an element.

Here is an example:

```css
.cat-parent>span {
  outline:none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cat-parent>span:after {
  content: "\f067";
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.children {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.cat-parent>span:focus+ul {
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* this will avoid the ul to disappear when we click its inner links*/

.cat-parent ul:hover {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="sidebar">

  <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-253 cat-parent">
      <a href="#">Various Fruits</a> <span class="count" tabindex=-1>(21)</span>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-255">
          <a href="#">Apples</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-254">
          <a href="#">Oranges</a> <span class="count">(20)</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: The most cross browser way is to use the anchor and use focus with `~`, this answer works in Chrome and possibly some other browsers but it does not work in FF. The OP did mention the html cannot be changed

Comment: @Huangism i simply went to fast ;) and was editing .. i had issue with postion of element, now it should work with FF too :)

Comment: @Huangism removed the span also. it was useless by the way ;)

Comment: You are missing my point `<span class="count" tabindex=-1>(21)</span>` that's extra html from the post, OP mentions the HTML cannot be changed

Comment: Thank you. I will try and implement it in just a few minutes and report back. :)

Comment: Oh I see, it's not part of the code OP displayed but it is in the snippet, but as far as I understand tabindex -1 cannot be added

Comment: @Huangism well if he cannot add attribute or manage classes i guess in this it won't be possible ... but we can add a small JS that will add this attribute ;)

Comment: Yea according to OP requirement js will be involved either way but then again if we are doing js, might as well just add a class when clicked and do everything else with simpler css selectors

Comment: Just wanted to report back that it does work. however, i went with the second example. And yes this did go out of line with the parameters, but is was good and could be implemented easily. Thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: @PressAwesome yes no problem ;) glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

While you can't make a click event in CSS, you can easily use jQuery to make it clickable and the child list [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). Since you can't edit the HTML, the best way is to get rid of your `:hover` state in CSS and made the `.children` list not visible by default. Then you can use the jQuery `.slideToggle()` method to make it appear on click.

You also can't target an `:after` element (ie your + button) since it's a pseudo element so you are going to have to target the entire row. See below for working example.

Don't forget to include jQuery in your script file: https://jquery.com/

```js
$('.cat-item-253').click(function(){
 $('.children').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.cat-parent:before{
  content:"\f067";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:250px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.children{
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="sidebar">

<ul class="product-categories">
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-253 cat-parent"><a href="#">Various Fruits</a> <span class="count">(21)</span>
          <ul class="children">
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-255">
                  <a href="#">Apples</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
               </li>
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-254">
                  <a href="#">Oranges</a> <span class="count">(20)</span>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: jquery not part of the question tags

Comment: Thank you, I got a couple of solutions. I will try this though and see what worked best, will report back soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `:hover` to `:active` or `:focus` like other suggested, but both don't work well. You can use `:target` instead. It only works with hyperlinks"

- Change the class `children` to an ID.
- Change the `href` of the main menu to `#children`.

Now when you click on the main menu, the sub-menu will appear. Click on any other link and the menu will fold up.

```css
.cat-parent:before{
  content:"\f067";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
  position:absolute;
  left:250px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#children{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#children:target{
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="sidebar">

<ul class="product-categories">
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-253 cat-parent"><a href="#children">Various Fruits</a> <span class="count">(21)</span>
          <ul id="children">
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-255">
                  <a href="#">Apples</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
               </li>
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-254">
                  <a href="#">Oranges</a> <span class="count">(20)</span>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

If you cannot change the HTML, there is just no way you can do it with pure CSS. You'll have to use JavaScript. You can do the entire effect in JavaScript, or if you like my CSS solution, then you can use JavaScript to change the two attributes like this:

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector(".cat-parent>a").href = "#children";
  document.querySelector(".children").id = "children";
})();
```

```css
.cat-parent:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#children {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#children:target {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="sidebar">

  <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-253 cat-parent"><a href="#">Various Fruits</a> <span class="count">(21)</span>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-255">
          <a href="#">Apples</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-254">
          <a href="#">Oranges</a> <span class="count">(20)</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: `NOTE: I can not change the HTML.`

Comment: Yeah, well, there is just no way it can be done in pure CSS without modifying the HTML, but at least this is the best CSS solution with minor changes. The `:focus` and `:active` don't work well. I could suggest using JS to change the attributes, but then the whole thing can be done in JS. But if the OP still prefers a CSS solution with minor JS, then I think this answer is their best bet.

Comment: The OP does prefer a CSS solution as long as the html don't change. I believe a js solution coupled with some css would do the trick

Comment: Yes, that's and that's what my solution does. Well, I can add the JS part, I guess.

Comment: But your current solution breaks the requirement of no html change and yes it is not possible to do what the OP wants with only CSS. I am just waiting for someone to post a solution which fits the requirement so I can upvote

Comment: I've already agreed and said I would add the JS part. I needed time to type it :). Now the second part has the exact HTML from the OP. 2 JS lines change the required attributes and the CSS does the job.